# Custom Signal for Plugin in Qt

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4, signals

My goal is to declare & implement a signal which will be triggered each time I press an action from menu. The Qt docs does not help me much in this direction.

Basically I must declare this signal in plugin interface, then emit this signal in plugin implementation file. This supposes to declare a slot, where I should to emit this signal. But it will be not called each time I press action.

The question is how to make a custom signal to work as standard signal `QAction::triggered`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [connect signals to other signals](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect) in Qt. This emits the second signal whenever the first one is emitted.

```
connect(menuAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SIGNAL(connectedSignal()));
```